# MySql: Sort 2 columns by certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have community table with following columns as shown below:

[image]

I need to sort table by "**ftr_order**" and "**isFeatured**" columns in a certain way that it displays data in the following order:

```
ftr_order | isFeatured

   2      |   yes
   1      |   no
   2      |   no
   3      |   no
   4      |   no
   5      |   no
   6      |   no
   0      |   no
   NULL   |   no
   NULL   |   no
   NULL   |   no
```

**ftr_order** should sort data in ascending order. 0 and NULL values should come at the bottom of the table.
I have tried the following query, this resolved it to some extent, but I need to set priority i.e.

i) ***First Priority***: If **isFeatured** is **yes** then show it on the top.

ii) ***Second Priority***: Sort **ftr_order** in ascending order

** **Note:** If **ftr_order** is *0* or *NULL* then display data at bottom.

```
SELECT * FROM community ORDER BY if(ftr_order = 0 or ftr_order is null,1,0), ftr_order ASC, community_description ASC
```

This displays the following output:

[image]

Here you can see that **ftr_order** has been sorted out correctly but one thing is missing here, **ID** number 7 should be listed on the top of the table as this row has column **isFeatured**='yes'. In order to bring this row on the top I tried to resolve it by writing down the query:

```
SELECT * FROM community ORDER BY if(ftr_order = 0 or ftr_order is null,1,0 or isFeatured='yes'), ftr_order ASC, community_description ASC
```

You can see the following output is generated and you can also analyze what issue is still left. **ID** number 7 should be listed on the top of the table, but here **ID** number 7 is listed at the bottom of the table.
Therefore I need to shift it on the top. Please help me out to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What is the pattern?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA : Please refresh the page again, you will see the pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer to my own question, solution is as follows:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * FROM `community` ORDER BY if( ftr_order =0 OR ftr_order IS NULL , 1, 0 ) , ftr_order ASC , community_description ASC) as community ORDER BY CASE WHEN isFeatured ='yes' then isFeatured END desc
```

Following output will be generated:

[image]

Here **isFeatured**='yes' is at the top and rest of the data is order by ftr_order ascending where NULL and 0 will come at the end.

```
ftr_order | isFeatured

   2      |   yes
   1      |   no
   2      |   no
   3      |   no
   4      |   no
   5      |   no
   6      |   no
   0      |   no
   NULL   |   no
   NULL   |   no
   NULL   |   no
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM community ORDER BY isfeatured desc, ftr_order ASC, community_description ASC

You can try like this if isfeatured has only yes/no make it simple